# How Can I Bind/Render An ASP.NET Dataset As Buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, user-interface, webforms

Using ASP.NET WebForms, what is a good approach for taking a DataSet and, instead of binding it to a linear ListBox or DropDownList control (for example), binding it to a control which looks like set of buttons or toggles which might be lined up or stacked etc.?

An example UI implementation might look like a numeric keypad...

```
Please Choose:
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
[7] [8] [9]
Submit >>
```

...where the numbers 1..9 have come from the DataSet (representing some data structure, maybe a set of product IDs to select), have been rendered as a keypad, and the user may click/select one or more items/buttons. When they have finished, they click Submit and the control's event(s) handle the Submit to extract the selected item data (i.e. the ID of the bound item/row).

As an extension, this would be a reusable control so that we could then do something like this...

```
Step 1. Please Choose item:
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
[7] [8] [9]
Submit >>

----------------------

You selected: 1, 5, 8
Step 2. Please Choose Sub-item:
[A] [B] [C] [D] [E] [F]
[G] [H] [I] [J] [K] [L]
[M] [N] [O] [P] [Q] [R]
Submit >>

----------------------

You selected: J, Q
Step 3. Please Choose Sub-sub-item:
[Apple] [Pear] [Orange]
[Kiwi] [Lemon] [Grape]
Submit >>
```

...where the user has selected from Step 1, then the Step 2 control is dynamically created/populated/rendered based on their Step 1 selection(s), then they select from Step 2 which renders Step 3 (based on 2), and then Step 3 selects are made, etc. etc., until the final Submit which does whatever it does behind the scenes.

Is there an existing ASP.NET control which enables the UI side of things, or perhaps it requires some heavy lifting all or in part by extra JavaScript (e.g. jQuery)? (The binding and dynamic creation is something I can do already of course with User Controls and the like.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [checkbox-list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control to get what you wanted. Here is an example markup that you can use:

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList id="checkboxlist1" 
       AutoPostBack="True"
       CellPadding="5"
       CellSpacing="5"
       RepeatColumns="2"
       RepeatDirection="Vertical"
       RepeatLayout="Flow"
       TextAlign="Right"
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="Check_Clicked"
       runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And then you can use [jqueryui button](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox) to get custom styling in client side.